# SAS count of distinct variables - Data Step

Tags: sas

I want to do the same thing in data step without proc sql.
note:variable1 is a character variable

```
proc sql;
 select count(distinct(variable1)),variable2,varibale3      
        from tablename group by variable2,variable3;
quit;
```

TIA

Comment: Why data step and not PROC step?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on the assumption that you actually wanted your result without using PROC SQL.

Breaking the solution in different steps to keep it very simple and easier for you to understand.:-

```
/*Step 1 This step just keeps the required variables in the dataset*/

    data tablename(keep=variable1 variable2 variable3);
    set tablename;
    run;

/*Step 2 Sorting and using noduprecs to keep distinct records in the table*/ 
    Proc sort data=tablename nodupkey;
    by _all_;
    run;

/*Step 3 Creating a tag as 1, so as to enable us to sum or count the distinct values*/
    Data tablename;
    set tablename;
    tag=1;
    run;

/*Step 4 Using Proc means to sum the tag inside var on the combination of Variable1 and Variable3 which is inside the Class*/  

/*I have used PROC MEANS here. You can do the same thing using PROC TABULATE or PROC REPORT*/

    proc means data=tablename sum;
      class variable2 variable3;
      var tag;
    run;
```

Let me know if you still have any questions

Comment: I sorted the datset but didnt use nodupkey option so it doesnt give the result now its working fine

Comment: @rocky If this solution has helped you, please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a data step, use a double proc freq.

```
proc freq data=have noprint;
table variable2*variable3*variable1 /out= first_summary;
run;

proc freq data=first_summary noprint;
table variable2*variable3 / out=want;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Comment: I think your second table should be `variable2*variable3`?

Answer (score 0):

`NLEVELS` option in `PROC FREQ` is the simplest way to get this.  Assuming it's sorted by the variable2/variable3, it's straightforward.  Here's an example using `sashelp.class`; here `sex` stands in for variable2 and variable3, and `age` stands in for the counted variable.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by sex;
run;

ods output nlevels=levels_age_sex;  *nlevels table is output;
proc freq data=class nlevels;       *nlevels here asked for output;
by sex;                             *grouping variable;
tables age/noprint;                 *do not actually want table;
run;
ods output close;                   *technically unnecessary but I like symmetry;
```